# Was not able to set foreign keys in tables with gorm data models

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm, datamodel

I am trying to set foreign key in the data models using gorm
this is the code that I have written

```
package main

import (
    "log"

    "database/sql/driver"
    "encoding/json"
    "errors"
    "time"

    "gorm.io/driver/postgres"
    "gorm.io/gorm"
)

type JSONB map[string]interface{}

func (j JSONB) Value() (driver.Value, error) {
    if j == nil {
        return nil, nil
    }
    return json.Marshal(j)
}

func (j *JSONB) Scan(value interface{}) error {
    b, ok := value.([]byte)
    if !ok {
        return errors.New("failed to unmarshal JSONB value")
    }

    var v interface{}
    if err := json.Unmarshal(b, &v); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    *j, ok = v.(map[string]interface{})
    if !ok {
        return errors.New("failed to convert JSONB value")
    }

    return nil
}

type Tag struct {
    Tag_id   int    `gorm:"primary_key;not null"`
    Tag_name string `gorm:"type:varchar(255);not null"`
}

type User_Entity struct {
    Id    string `gorm:"type:varchar(36);not null;unique"`
    Email string `gorm:"type:varchar(255);not null"`
}

type Log_Settings struct {
    Log_Setting_Id   int    `gorm:"primary_key;not null"`
    Log_Setting_Name string `gorm:"type:varchar(20);not null"`
    Creator_Id       string `gorm:"type:varchar(36);not null"`

    User_Entity User_Entity `gorm:"foreignKey:Creator_Id"`
}

type Pass_Fail_Categories struct {
    Category_Id   int    `gorm:"primary_key;unique;not null"`
    Category_Name string `gorm:"type:varchar(15);not null"`
}

type Pass_Fail_Category_Messages struct {
    Category_Id      int    `gorm:"not null"`
    Messages string `gorm:"type:varchar(50);unique;not null"`

    Pass_Fail_Categories Pass_Fail_Categories `gorm:"foreignKey:Category_Id"`
}

type Pass_Fail_Criteria_Feilds struct {
    Criteria_Id      int    `gorm:"primary_key;not null"`
    Category_Id      int    `gorm:"not null"`
    Category_Message string `gorm:"type:varchar(50);not null"`
    Numeric_Operator string `gorm:"type:varchar(2);not null"`
    Criteria_Value   int    `gorm:"not null"`

        Pass_Fail_Categories *Pass_Fail_Categories `gorm:"foreignKey:Category_Id"`
        Pass_Fail_Category_Messages Pass_Fail_Category_Messages `gorm:"foreignKey:Category_Message;references:Messages"`
}

func main() {
    db, err := gorm.Open(postgres.Open("host=localhost user=postgres password=1234567 dbname=tester port=5432 sslmode=disable"), &gorm.Config{})
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("connection failed")
    }

    db.AutoMigrate(&Tag{})
    db.AutoMigrate(&User_Entity{})
    db.AutoMigrate(&Pass_Fail_Categories{})
    db.AutoMigrate(&Pass_Fail_Category_Messages{})
    db.AutoMigrate(&Pass_Fail_Criteria_Feilds{})
}
```

Here I am then auto migrating these tables but for some cases the foreign keys are not getting reflect and for sometimes it's giving error

```
"CREATE TABLE Pass_Fail_Criteria_Feilds
(
  Criteria_Id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  Category_Id INTEGER REFERENCES Pass_Fail_Categories(Category_Id) NOT NULL,
  Category_Message VARCHAR(50) REFERENCES Pass_Fail_Category_Messages(Messages) NOT NULL,
  Numeric_Operator VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL,
  Criteria_Value INTEGER NOT NULL
)"
```

this is a table structure that I am trying to achieve how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are connected to the correct database and have the necessary permissions to create tables and establish foreign key relationships, I would recommend first that you handle *all* errors: that will give you more information on what is going on.

```golang
func main() {
    db, err := gorm.Open(postgres.Open("host=localhost user=postgres password=1234567 dbname=tester port=5432 sslmode=disable"), &gorm.Config{})
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Connection failed: %v", err)
    }

    // Ensure that referenced tables are created first
    if err := db.AutoMigrate(&Pass_Fail_Categories{}); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to auto-migrate Pass_Fail_Categories: %v", err)
    }

    if err := db.AutoMigrate(&Pass_Fail_Category_Messages{}); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to auto-migrate Pass_Fail_Category_Messages: %v", err)
    }

    if err := db.AutoMigrate(&Pass_Fail_Criteria_Fields{}); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to auto-migrate Pass_Fail_Criteria_Fields: %v", err)
    }

    // ... other AutoMigrate calls ...
}
```

Make sure that the column you are referencing as a foreign key exists in the other table and that its data type matches the foreign key column.
For example, `Pass_Fail_Categories` should have a column `Category_Id` before you can use it as a foreign key in another table.

It is important that the tables referenced by foreign keys are created before the tables that reference them. In your `main` function, make sure you are calling `AutoMigrate` in the correct order.

Finally, In GORM, you have to ensure that you follow the [GORM conventions for naming foreign keys](https://gorm.io/docs/gorm_config.html#naming_strategy), or explicitly specify the foreign key constraints using the struct tags (which you did with `gorm:"foreignKey:Creator_Id"`).